# How can I import files with specific encoding in Jackcess?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jackcess

I was playing with the Jackcess library trying to import some csv files to an Access file using this code:

> Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb")); new
>   ImportUtil.Builder(db, "Imported2").setDelimiter(",").importFile(new
>   File("my.csv")); db.close();

It works but I was wondering where can I specify the character enconding for the input file because I have several files encoded with 8859-2, 8859-1, 8859-7 and the imported rows have wrong characters.

How can this be done with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `importReader()` instead of `importFile()`.